# SEO - My web page ranks by images but no by content

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, negative-seo

I have a page with original content which **only ranks my images but don't rank the articles**. The images appears in SERPS with an interesting graphic of impressions:

[image]

As you can see in picture I've made two important SEO actions. One of those was change all the **titles whose have a supicious pattern** like:

*descargar [program name] gratis - reviews*

The other one was change all the outlinks which was not correct contextualized adding **nofollow**. This action doesn't have inmediat effects. The **number of clicks keep in 1 per day at least**. This action was suggested in this [Google forum question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/webmaster-es/KErNwmOMX50/vx-_ntc4q4MJ)

As you can see in this graphic, the number of visits doesn't change proportionally with the number of impressions:

[image]

After analyses I saw that the source of the **impressions are only results where appear and image** of mine:

[image]

But for querys which shown articles doesn't appears on SERPS:

*programas para abrir documentos docx -> 1 impression on position 11*

[Link to article](http://descargarprogramasgratis.eu/lista-de/abrir-documentos-docx), and **doesn't appears on google result page in any page (looking for the first 30 pages)**. This pattern is reproduced for every article page.

Years ago (2012) **I was banned** with a web called yubil (now doesn't exists). After that I created **two more webs with original content**, totally diferent content, and any of those have a visit a day (during a year). After that I deleted the web and domain:

- Could be any relation?
- Do you have any idea about what I'm doing wrong?
- It is normal be banned on articles but no in images?

Any help would be strongly apreciated.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Very detailed question- it took some time to write I am sure. I will have to sort this out in my mind a bit. Meanwhile, when you say that *yubil* was banned, do you mean by Google? How did you know? And why was it banned? While Google keeps track of these things for Trust, I doubt if this is your issue. The effect would have existed from the beginning of your two new sites.

Comment: Sorry for not detail it a little bit more. Yubil was an aggregator of Twitter accounts present it as people search engine. I have **lots of thin and automatic content** and after panda begins, goes down from 300 to 4 visits a day. I never received any messages from webmastertools

After that I created 2 new blogs. About investment and basic healthy. These two had no automatic content and was 100% original. But **never gets more than 5 impressions a day**, and **have 1 visit a week at least**. Its interface was very similar to the blog I've linked in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I took a look at https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/webmaster-es/KErNwmOMX50/vx-_ntc4q4MJ and your page at http://descargarprogramasgratis.eu/lista-de/abrir-documentos-docx.

I do like your article. It appears to be rather good!

I am making some assumptions that may not be right. If this is not the case, do not worry about my assumptions. I mention them in case they are helpful. Part of my assumption comes from the Google forum link and some of what you say here in order to get a full view. It appears that some rather common fundamental misunderstandings are in play. I will addressing these.

***There are several things that have to be considered immediately if a website is to be made.***

- What is my goal for the site?
- Can I make a website that is useful to users?
- Is the site topic something people are looking for?
- Am I chasing keywords and overly concerned with placement?
- Does the topic and topic keywords return valuable results?

I will explain these and others:

**What is my goal for the site?**

If the goal for your site is Adsense revenue, you have a serious up-hill battle. The fact is this; if you are trying to attract users for ad revenue, your site has to attract at least 200-300 users per day before it begins to pay. The site/page topic must be one that generates a reasonable CPC (cost per-click) and CPM (cost per-thousand ad impressions) value. As well, the site/page topic must match the users interest in that they are more likely to click on an ad. For example, product reviews attract users who are interested in a purchasing. Does your site do this? If not, then the CTR (click-through rates) will be lower. For sites that are informational, then the site may suffer in lower CTR, but will enjoy high metrics such as returning users, time spent on page, time spent on site, lower bounce rates, etc. This will make up for the lower CTR by recapturing your users attention and giving the plenty of opportunities to click on an ad. There is a funny effect that you may not be aware of. If a user trusts your site, likes your content, and returns several times, the likelihood of that user clicking on an ad is extremely high. Their trust for you is transferred to the ad.

The best goal for any site is to be helpful to users and not focused on search. By creating content for users, you are putting a bit of yourself into the site. Users like this. Be yourself and do not be afraid to show your personality. Users want to trust your site and will if they like *you*.

**Can I make a website that is useful to users?**

The answer based upon your one article is Yes! Sites that fit this model require a lot of content in order to compete but well worth pursuing.

**Am I chasing keywords and overly concerned with placement?**

When starting a website, the focus must be on content, content, and content. The higher the quality the better. It takes a long time for a site to find it's footing. It can take a couple of years in fact. So the first focus is to create a site that users want, find useful, will reference, will return to, will link to, will share, etc. Keywords are important, but in the early stage, I suggest being more natural than artificial. Once established, then you can better focus on keywords. The SEO industry has wrongly focused on keywords too much and makes it seem that success is tied to keywords first when the truth is that success is tied to content first. Do not worry about keywords. Worry about content.

**Does the topic and topic keywords return valuable results?**

This is a much tougher topic. Sometimes there is a reason why keywords and topics are lower in competition and that finding a place in this niche market will result in a lower traffic site. As well, some topics do well in English, but not other languages. Part of this is the limited search due to topics not being sought in Internet developing countries. This will change. However, there will always be topics that do well in certain countries and languages. Keep this in mind.

Even for English language sites, lower competition keywords and topics can seriously result in lower traffic. On the other side of the coin, the higher competition keywords and topics may be too hard to compete for a new site and will take years of work. The idea is to find a useful topic that people are searching for where the topic/market has not been flooded with sites and where people are interested and there is search for but not covered well.

**The web requires a foundation of trust.**

Any website must seek trust first long before content and search traffic. The trust metrics are too vast to cover here, but know that I count 46 factors that signal trust. There are factors that you will not control over such as site age. But you should explore seeking trust before keywords. Without trust, can a search engine place your site link high in the SERPs (search engine result pages)? The answer is No.

**Stop the keyword chase.**

Focusing too much on keywords too much will limit your search results. For prose based topics, one of the first tactics I recommend is simply avoiding keyword focusing. Create useful `title` tags, `description` meta-tags, header tags, content, and so on that are geared toward users, conversational, natural, and compelling. This should be your first focus. I recommend this for a simple reason. Once the page is in the SERPs and the page begins to return uses to your site, you will be able to see what keywords your page should rank for and then begin to make small changes to increase your position. Otherwise, you may be making bad assumptions. As well, making larger sweeping changes search performance enough to confuse the issue. Small changes that are made only after a few months between changes does a couple for things: one, it allows search engines to re-index your pages and recalculate how your pages should perform; and two, give you enough time to see the effects. Otherwise, you will never be able to measure your results as search engines are constantly re-calculating your SERP metrics. SEO is a very very slow process. Please also keep in mind that pages rank. You have to work on one page at a time, however, once you get how your site should perform, it is a matter of doing essentially the same thing for all of your pages.

Keep in mind that using strong keyword signals may/will keep any page from performing as it should. I have seen this over and over again. Strong keyword signals will hurt a site or page if the keywords are not right. For text based pages, the less the better. Smaller signals go a long way and allow you to study your performance and make subtle changes that really increase your search performance. A word to the wise.

**Web success requires focus.**

It is always advisable to have just on domain especially if you are new to web creation and SEO. The reasons for this are simple. With one site you will be able to focus on content and quality without diluting your efforts. As well, since sites are linked into realms where sites are related, one poor performing site may/can effect others. Your past penalized domain may/can be haunting your new sites. But this can be easily overcome. Keep reading.

**Here is the good news.**

Search engines, especially Google, are rather forgiving. If you build a high quality site, search engines want you to succeed. It is good for their businesses bottom line that your site succeeds. As well, search engines understand that new sites are new. They also understand human effort and appreciate it.

Since your previous penalized site appeared automated, you need to avoid having your new site(s) follow this format. Make sites for humans. While automated data sites can perform well, this seems to be within limits that should be avoided. The reason for this is simple. These sites require a huge amount of content pages and a significant amount of content per page. These sites take many years to compete and rank well.

However, human created sites are heavily rewarded. But still, any site must have content. Prepare yourself for generating at least 300 pages of good quality content. Your linked article is very good! If you keep generating content like this one page, you will do well and perform as you should. Keep in mind that the more pages you have, the more opportunities you have to attract a user, please a user, and have that user return. But do not be in too much of a hurry. One odd effect is this. Sites that are consistently updated with new content, even one or a few pages per week, often perform best. What will happen is that after a period, your site, if done well, will gain an audience and perform better as each page is added. It is an up-sweeping line on a graph. It takes a while to get started, and after a period of struggling, the site will suddenly take off. Consistency is the key. Progress if made consistently over a period of time will be trusted and rewarded both by search engines and users. These are often the best sites!

Comment: Strongly complete the answer. Excelent, I only can say, thank you very much.

Comment: @Miguel Thank you very much. When you need me, I am here. We all are. I am here everyday though sometimes I do have to run my business. ;-) Unfortunate as that may be.